# modifiedmk Mann-Kendall Test Over NC /Raster stack

Tags: raster, r, regression, rasterstack

I am working with NetCDF file for analysis of trend. I am using the following codes for analysis of trend..

```
library(modifiedmk)
library(raster)

    I <- brick("I.nc")
    d <- stack(I)
    tsfun = function(x,na.rm){
      if(all(is.na(x))){return(NaN)}
      return(pwmk(x)[["Sen's Slope"]])
    }

    t <- calc(d, fun=tsfun, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The above codes are doing good but when I'm replacing [["Sen's Slope"]] with other names it is throwing an error saying "Error in pwmk(x)[["P-value"]] : subscript out of bounds"

The function is stable with only two arguments [["Sen's Slope"]] and [["old. Sen's Slope"]]. I need P-Value, Tau and Z-value. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

First, you are using a double bracket where you do not need to and second, it is often better to use a numeric index.

```
library(modifiedmk)
  x <- c(Nile)
```

Here, if you use a single bracket it returns the desired statistic.

```
pwmk(x)["P-value"]
```

Now, if you use a numeric index you can simplify things a bit. This returns the: "P-value", "Z-value", "Sen's Slope" and "Tau", in that order.

```
pwmk(x)[c(4,1,2,7)]
```

Comment: Again, the function is only working with Sen's Slope. The raster stack have cells with NA values is that causing a problem? and with the numeric index "Error in setValues(out, x) : 
  values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor" this error is occuring. How can I handle the NA in the function?

Comment: tsfun = function(x,na.rm){
    if(all(is.na(x))){return(NaN)}
    return(pwmk(x)["P-value"])
     }
> t <- calc(d, fun=tsfun, na.rm = F) 
> t
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 129, 135, 17415  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : 66.375, 100.125, 6.375, 38.625  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : NA, NA  (min, max)

Comment: Since you are writing out to a raster stack, you need to have the same number of NA's as output values (raster layers). Something like: `if(all(is.na(x))){ return(rep(NA,4)) }`